# rename phylo tip labels

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I want to give a species a new name in my tree of class `phylo` (using the `ape` package).

I tried:

```
tree$tip.label["speciesX"] <- "speciesY"
```

This did not do what I wanted. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't index the tip labels the way you want (you want to replace the tip label whose *value* is "speciesX", not the one whose *name* is "speciesX"; the tip label vector doesn't have names).  Silly as it sounds, you need something like `tree$tip.label[tree$tip.label=="speciesX"]` to identify the right value to replace.

Example:

```
## create a tree, from ?read.tree
s <- "owls(((Strix_aluco:4.2,Asio_otus:4.2):3.1,Athene_noctua:7.3):6.3,Tyto_alba:13.5);"
cat(s, file = "ex.tre", sep = "\n")
tree.owls <- read.tree("ex.tre")
```

Rename:

```
tree.owls$tip.label[tree.owls$tip.label=="Asio_otus"] <- "something_else"
```

You could write a function to do this, something like (not tested!)

```
rename.tips <- function(phy, old_names, new_names) {
   mpos <- match(old_names,phy$tip.labels)
   phy$tip.labels[mpos] <- new_names
   return(phy)
}
```